# Runtime error: Singly Link List program to insert a value

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I was writing a code in C for "A Singly Link List". In this code, I want to insert elements at the end of the list. It compiled fine. But during runtime, expected output is not coming. I am using `gcc` as compiler. Whenever I am doing `./a.out` in terminal it just got hanged.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct list
{
    int node;
    struct list *next; 
};

void insert(struct list *, int);
void print(struct list *);

int main()
{
    struct list *mylist;

    insert(mylist, 10);
    insert(mylist, 20);
    insert(mylist, 30);
    insert(mylist, 40);
    insert(mylist, 50);
    insert(mylist, 60);

    print(mylist);
    return 0;
}

void print(struct list *head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
            while(head->next!=NULL)
            {
             printf("%d\t",head->node);
             head=head->next;       
        }
    }
}


void insert(struct list *head, int value)
{   
    struct list *new_node;
    new_node = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

//node Creation
    new_node->node=value;
    new_node->next=NULL;

//Adding Node to list
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=new_node;  

    }
    else
    {
        while(head->next!=NULL);
        {   
            head=head->next;

        }
        head->next=new_node;

    }

}
```

Here `insert()` is the function which insert elements in `mylist` linklist and `print()` is a function which prints all values in the link list. Please help. I am not able to catch what mistake I have made.

Comment: Why do you tag a question that is explicitly C with C++? There is no such thing as C/C++

Comment: `mylist` is not initialized to `NULL`, but it seems important that this be done.

Comment: When I am initializing mylist to NULL then it always go in the **if** part of insert() function hence making no link list.

Comment: Run you app under Valgrind to see that there is a serious problem with `mylist`.

Comment: @Naman: if your list is not initialize to NULL then you try to access a memory location which is not defined when you execute `head->next` or `head->node`. The first insert call will create a memory allocated for node which thee list will point at.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest one more change, i.e. the prototypes of the functions should be like

```
void insert(struct list **, int);
void print(struct list **);
```

and the body should be changed accordingly. As you have done new memory allocations in insert and so you should not do a pass by value rather it should be pass by address then only it will work as intended.

Moreover, in print function the loop termination should be
    while(*head != NULL) instead of    while((*head)->next != NULL)  otherwise it will skip the last node.

Also you should store the first node into a tmp pointer after you invoke   insert  function first time and that  tmp  pointer should be passed into   print  function  at the end. In your code you are passing the pointer to last node which is wrong. So, it should be like.

```
int main()
{
    struct list *mylist=NULL, *tmp = NULL;

    insert(&mylist, 10);

    tmp = mylist;   /* here */

    insert(&mylist, 20);
    insert(&mylist, 30);
    insert(&mylist, 40);
    insert(&mylist, 50);
    insert(&mylist, 60);

    /* At this point mylist is pointing to last node, so pass tmp which stores the first node */
    print(&tmp);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually the insert change is needed but not the print one (but it is better i agree)

Comment: Double indirection is not necessary nor recommended for `print()`.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with following line,

```
 while(head->next!=NULL);
```

It should be,

```
 while(head->next!=NULL)
```

Remove semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors:

1) your code writers `struct list *head;`. Do you know that in C and C++ such a variable is not initialized? You cannot count on it being `NULL` unless it's at global scope; local variables instead must always be initialized before being used.

2) your insert function receives `head` by value so when it changes it (in the case the list is empty) it's only modifying its local copy and not the `head` variable of `main`. You must either pass `head` as a `struct list **` or you must return the new `head` value to main. In C++ an alternative is to pass it as a `list *&` (reference to a pointer).

3) Your `while` loop has an extra semicolon at before the body so it's an empty loop and the body part will be executed always (no matter what is the condition) and exactly once because it's just a nested `{...}` block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good infinite loop. If you use a debugger, you could have found it yourself ^^.

```
while(head->next!=NULL);
```

After you also need to initialize your list in your main function.

```
struct list *mylist = NULL;
```

youalso need to changeyour insert argument to be a double pointer (the main head list value change should will not occur if you pass the its pointer only since it just copy the address value)

```
void print(struct list *head)
{
  while(head!=NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\t",head->node);
    head=head->next;       
  }
}

void insert(struct list **head, int value)
{   
  struct list *new_node;
  new_node = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

  //node Creation
  new_node->node=value;
  new_node->next=NULL;

  //Get the end of the list
  while((*head)->next!=NULL)
  {   
    (*head)=(*head)->next;
  }

  // Add the node at the end of the list
  (*head)->next=new_node;
}

int main()
{
  struct list *mylist = NULL;

  insert(&mylist, 10);
  insert(&mylist, 20);
  insert(&mylist, 30);
  insert(&mylist, 40);
  insert(&mylist, 50);
  insert(&mylist, 60);

  print(mylist);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: paper.plane also point out that your insert function argument must be `struct list **head` and not `struct list *head` I will correct my answer for it

Answer (score 1):

While it does not immediately solve your problem, also note that the memory that is dynamically allocated is not freed in your application: your program leaks.

It would be highly recommendable to add another function `destroy`:

```
void destroy(list * head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        struct list * tmp = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = tmp;
    }
}
```

Here is a complete working example, that does not leak: http://ideone.com/y2Fl7i